# Centering a fluid container

Tags: html, css

I have a joomla site with a slide show in it thus:

`<div id="homePageRotator">
      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="homePageRotator" style="xhtml" />
      <!--homePageRotator--></div>`

It works fine and is responsive. ON small screens I want it to fill the width, which it does.

But there are some screen sizes when I'd like it centered in the column - ie when the original images are smaller than the column width - which does happen.

Normally I'd do this with something like:

```
#homePageRotator {
        width:300px;margin:0 auto;
    }
```

which obviously wont work with this because the width is fluid.

Ideally I want the width to be 100% - so the pictures are as large as possible.

But if I add 100% there can't be any margin!!!!

SO I have tried added another wrapper around the #homePageRotator but I can't make it work

Any ideas please!

http://www.link-property-services.co.uk/

Thanks

Comment: share your code or place link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
#homePageRotator {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This should grow or shrink to 100% of the content and place it in the middle.

Comment: interesting - tried that, and now its disappeared completely.

Comment: got it back by adding float:none; clear:both; - still not centered though

Comment: The auto margin centering option will not work with  a width of `auto`. However, it will work with % widths and `max-width`

Comment: thanks Paulie_D - its working now - but I dont like my solution, which  used width:480px; max-width:90%;